# Copy DataFrame with NaN values in Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like the example below.

```py
# define DataFrame for reproducability

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-05-06', '2019-05-07', '2019-05-07', '2019-05-09', '2019-05-10', '2019-05-11'],
                   'Identifier': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'B': [2.4, 3.9, 3.9, 4.3, 2.5, 3.14],
                   'C': [0.214, 0.985, 0.985, 0.839, 0.555, 0.159],
                   'Name': [np.nan, "CD", "AD", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

print(df)

    date        Identifier  B       C       Name
0   2019-05-06  1           2.40    0.214   NaN
1   2019-05-07  1           3.90    0.985   CD
2   2019-05-07  1           3.90    0.985   AD
3   2019-05-09  1           4.30    0.839   NaN
4   2019-05-10  1           2.50    0.555   NaN
5   2019-05-11  1           3.14    0.159   NaN
```

What can be seen is that, for a given identifier, there *can* be more than one name. However, the name is only appended to the DataFrame once at a single date. What I need is to basically forward **and backward** fill the names at every date. Currently, I have a solution that works, but that is extremely slow for the full dataframe that I am working on. The code is shown below

```py
final_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in df.Identifier.unique():
    # select the current identifier
    identifier_df = df.loc[df.Identifier == i]
    # allow a given identifier to have different names
    for n in df.Name.unique():
        if pd.isna(n):
            continue
        else:
            intermediate = identifier_df.copy()
            intermediate.loc[:,"Name"] = np.repeat(n, len(intermediate))
            final_df = final_df.append(intermediate)

final_df = final_df.drop_duplicates()
```

Note that the loop through identifiers is required for my full DataFrame. In this instance, however, it seems rather pointless. This code, nevertheless, results in the following DataFrame (which is how I would like the output to be):

```py
print(final_df)

    date        Identifier  B       C       Name
0   2019-05-06  1           2.40    0.214   CD
1   2019-05-07  1           3.90    0.985   CD
3   2019-05-09  1           4.30    0.839   CD
4   2019-05-10  1           2.50    0.555   CD
5   2019-05-11  1           3.14    0.159   CD
0   2019-05-06  1           2.40    0.214   AD
1   2019-05-07  1           3.90    0.985   AD
3   2019-05-09  1           4.30    0.839   AD
4   2019-05-10  1           2.50    0.555   AD
5   2019-05-11  1           3.14    0.159   AD
```

Is there any way to perform this operation with a groupby, or is there any other way to make it faster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to speed up this code by a significant amount is by appending the intermediate DataFrames to a list first, and concatenate the list of DataFrames in one final step using `pd.concat()`.

This would make the code look as follows:

```
final_df = []

for i in df.Identifier.unique():
    # select the current identifier
    identifier_df = df.loc[df.Identifier == i]
    # allow a given identifier to have different names
    for n in df.Name.unique():
        if pd.isna(n):
            continue
        else:
            intermediate = identifier_df.copy()
            intermediate.loc[:,"Name"] = np.repeat(n, len(intermediate))
            final_df.append(intermediate)


final_df = pd.concat(final_df).drop_duplicates()
```

This simple solution made me decrease execution time by a significant margin. Hopefully it helps someone else as well.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, if dates are sorted and each date has same length:

```
from itertools import islice,cycle
m=df.name.isna() #pull where name is NaN
l=df.loc[~m,'name'].tolist() #create a list for not null names
df.loc[m,'name']=list(islice(cycle(l),len(df[m]))) #repeat the list for all dates and assign to NaN
print(df)
```

---

```
         date  identifier    B      C name
0  2019-05-07           1  2.4  0.214   AB
1  2019-05-07           1  2.4  0.214   CD
2  2019-05-08           1  3.9  0.985   AB
3  2019-05-08           1  3.9  0.985   CD
4  2019-05-09           1  2.5  0.555   AB
5  2019-05-09           1  2.5  0.555   CD
```

Comment: If I sort my dataframe (sort_values) on date and identifier, then using this approach will unfortunately yield me much more names per identifier than should actually be present. The same happens if I only sort on date.

Comment: @MennoVanDijk I see. I assumed all the dates have equal names.

Comment: I see now, that is indeed not the case. Each date has several different names, sometimes a couple of names get added at a given date, and sometimes a couple of names drop out at a given date. Thank you kindly for your attempt already.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for all combination of all 3 columns:

```
from  itertools import product

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df['date'].unique(), 
                                df['Identifier'].unique(),
                                df['Name'].dropna().unique())), 
                   columns=['date','Identifier','Name'])
print (df1)
         date  Identifier Name
0  2019-05-06           1   CD
1  2019-05-06           1   AD
2  2019-05-07           1   CD
3  2019-05-07           1   AD
4  2019-05-09           1   CD
5  2019-05-09           1   AD
6  2019-05-10           1   CD
7  2019-05-10           1   AD
8  2019-05-11           1   CD
9  2019-05-11           1   AD
```

Left join by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df2 = df1.merge(df, how='left').set_index(['date','Identifier'])
```

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for possible replace missing values by [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df3 = df.drop_duplicates(['date','Identifier']).set_index(['date','Identifier'])
print (df3)
                          B      C Name
date       Identifier                  
2019-05-06 1           2.40  0.214  NaN
2019-05-07 1           3.90  0.985   CD
2019-05-09 1           4.30  0.839  NaN
2019-05-10 1           2.50  0.555  NaN
2019-05-11 1           3.14  0.159  NaN

df4 = df2.combine_first(df3).reset_index()
print (df4)
         date  Identifier     B      C Name
0  2019-05-06           1  2.40  0.214   CD
1  2019-05-06           1  2.40  0.214   AD
2  2019-05-07           1  3.90  0.985   CD
3  2019-05-07           1  3.90  0.985   AD
4  2019-05-09           1  4.30  0.839   CD
5  2019-05-09           1  4.30  0.839   AD
6  2019-05-10           1  2.50  0.555   CD
7  2019-05-10           1  2.50  0.555   AD
8  2019-05-11           1  3.14  0.159   CD
9  2019-05-11           1  3.14  0.159   AD
```

Comment: Very nice use of the helper series there. :) Clever..!!

Comment: This solution unfortunately only works correctly for one out of all unique names for a given identifier. When using
`df = df.sort_values(["date", "Identifier"])`

```s = df.groupby(['date','Identifier']).cumcount()```

```df['Name'] = df.groupby(['Identifier', s])['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())```

It only fills up one Name at all dates correctly, all other Names only get filled at dates where they are not NaN. (sorry for horrible formatting of code, can't seem to get it to work properly)

Comment: @jezrael I will provide an example in a few hours, currently working with a deadline so have to get some stuff ready. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: can you explain Cumcount() given 0,1 and then ['Name'].ffill() will take AB = 0 and CD  = 1 and fill the name column @jezrael .. need some explanation

Comment: @jezrael I messed up with the example, it is not actually how my data looks like. Can you look at my editted data and see if that makes more sense? Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael Unfortunately the edited version makes me run out of memory in my own code.

Comment: @MennoVanDijk - Answer was edited, please check it.

Comment: @jezrael Still giving me a memory error. Thank you a lot for your help, I'll probably just use my stick to my slower solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner `concat`, `replace`, slicing, and `ffill`:

```
print(pd.concat([df[::2],df[::2].replace('AB','CD')]).ffill())
```

Output:

```
         date  identifier    B      C name
0  2019-05-07           1  2.4  0.214   AB
2  2019-05-08           1  3.9  0.985   AB
4  2019-05-09           1  2.5  0.555   AB
0  2019-05-07           1  2.4  0.214   CD
2  2019-05-08           1  3.9  0.985   CD
4  2019-05-09           1  2.5  0.555   CD
```

Comment: This would work for the given example, but would not generalize well to my overall DataFrame (as there are 1600+ total names).

Comment: Unfortunately, even with a workaround, using 

```pd.concat([df[::2],df[::2].replace(df.name.unique())]).ffill().bfill() ```


gives me much more names at each identifier than should be the case